# ERROR: operator does not exist: integer <> integer[]

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a function where I am passing an array as parameter.

When I try to execute the function I get the following error:

```
[2020-12-07 13:53:58] [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: integer <> integer[]
[2020-12-07 13:53:58] Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
[2020-12-07 13:53:58] Where: PL/pgSQL function vectors_paginated(uuid,text,integer[]) line 16 at IF
```

This is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vectors_paginated(analysisId uuid, vectorName text, actors int[])
RETURNS SETOF vectors  AS $$
    DECLARE
        vector record;
        isValidVector bool;
    BEGIN
        FOR vector IN
            SELECT * FROM vectors AS aiv
            WHERE aiv.analysis_id = analysisId
        LOOP
            isValidVector:= true;
                
        IF isValidVector AND vectorName IS NOT NULL AND Lower(vector.name) NOT LIKE ('%' || Lower(vectorName) || '%') THEN
            isValidVector:= false;
        END IF;

        IF isValidVector AND actors IS NOT NULL AND vector.actor_type NOT IN (actors) THEN
            isValidVector:= false;
        END IF;

        IF isValidVector = true THEN
            RETURN NEXT vector;
        END IF;
        END LOOP;

        RETURN;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;



  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vectors_paginated(
    '0066ae29-e0a7-4d3e-9ab6-a7903b3683a8',
    null,
    ARRAY[0, 1]);
```

What am I doing  wrong?

Comment: There is no `<>` in the code you have shown us

Comment: This is the full script I have I assumes it was rrelated to how I was passing the parameter I added the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`not in` can't be used with an array, you need to use `vector.actor_type <> ALL (actors)`

---

But I think your whole function can be simplified substantially by putting your conditions in the WHERE and getting rid of the slow and inefficient row-by-row processing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vectors_paginated(analysisId uuid, vectorName text, actors int[])
  RETURNS SETOF vectors  
AS 
$$
  SELECT aiv.*
  FROM vectors AS aiv
  WHERE aiv.analysis_id = analysisId
    AND (vectorName is NULL OR Lower(aiv.name) NOT LIKE '%' || Lower(vectorName) || '%')
    AND (actors IS NULL OR aiv.actor_type <> ALL (actors));
$$
language SQL;
```